# Maximum absolute difference in an array

Tags: algorithm

I came across this algorithm question. I was able to implement a O(n^2) solution. Is there a better way of doing this in O(n) time?

**Question:**

You are given an array of N integers, `A1, A2 ,…, AN`. Return maximum value of `f(i, j)` for all `1 ≤ i, j ≤ N`.
`f(i, j)` is defined as `|A[i] - A[j]| + |i - j|`, where `|x|` denotes absolute value of x.

**Example**:

```
A=[1, 3, -1]

f(1, 1) = f(2, 2) = f(3, 3) = 0
f(1, 2) = f(2, 1) = |1 - 3| + |1 - 2| = 3
f(1, 3) = f(3, 1) = |1 - (-1)| + |1 - 3| = 4
f(2, 3) = f(3, 2) = |3 - (-1)| + |2 - 3| = 5
```

So, we return 5.

**My Answer:**

```
public class Solution {
    public int maxArr(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
        int maxSum = 0;

        for(int i=1; i<=A.size()-1; i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<=A.size(); j++){
                int tempSum = sum(A.get(i-1), A.get(j-1), i, j);

                if(tempSum > maxSum) {
                    maxSum = tempSum;
                }
            }
        }

        return maxSum;
    }

    public int sum(int Ai, int Aj, int i, int j) {
        return Math.abs(Ai-Aj) + Math.abs(i-j);
    }
}
```

Also in my solution the inner loop runs from i + 1 to N, so the worst case is N-1 for that loop. Is my overall solution still O(n^2)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, your solution is still `O(N^2)` as `(N - 1) + (N - 2) + ... + 1 = N * (N - 1) / 2`.

I'll show how to solve a more general problem in linear time: give a list of points in 2D space (x[i], y[i]), find two farthest points (with respect to Manhattan distance).

1. Let's find the following points: max(x[i] + y[i]), max(-x[i] + y[i]), max(-y[i] + x[i]) and max(-x[i] - y[i]) among all i.
2. Let's compute the distance between every point in the list and the four points chosen during the previous step and pick the largest one. This algorithm clearly works in linear time as it considers `4 * N` pairs of points. I claim that it's correct.
3. Why? Let's fix a point (x[k], y[k]) and try to find the farthest one from it. Consider an arbitrary point (x[i], y[i]). Let's expand the absolute value of differences between their coordinates. Let's assume that it's `x[i] + x[k] + y[i] + y[k] = (x[k] + y[k]) + x[i] + y[i]`. The first term is a constant. If `x[i] + y[i]` is not maximum among all `i`, `(x[i], y[i])` cannot be the farthest. The three other cases (depending on the sign of x[i] and y[i] in the expansion) are handled in the same manner.

Comment: Isn't it enough to check the two possible axes for the maximum (i.e. max(+x,+y)/max(-x,-y) and max(+x,-y)/max(-x,+y)?

Comment: Actually, it is. This becomes clearer if you transform the distance to L-infinity. Then you get `max(d(p1, p2)) = max(max(|x1+y1-x2-y2|, |x1-y1-x2+y2|))` And the maximum is reached by either of the pairs in my previous comment.

Comment: I am still trying to understand how the general solution will help me. So I could find two farthest points in the array using your method and substitute their values in the equation to find the maximum absolute difference?

Comment: @Yeshwanth Venkatesh  You can just set x[i] = a [i] and y[i] = i for all i.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still struggling to understand this solution. Why should I set y[i] = i? I thought it was x[i] = a [i] and y[i] = a [j]? We just need to find the min and max value in the array and substitute their values in the formula right?

Comment: After looking at the formula for manhattan distance, I understand how your solution applies to this problem. You are trying to find the largest distance between two points `x,y` where `x = (A[i],i)` and `y = (A[j],j)`?

Comment: In the point #3 when you are trying to find the absolute value of difference between two points. Shouldn't it be `(x[k] + y[k]) - x[i] + y[i]` instead of `(x[k] + y[k]) + x[i] + y[i]`

Comment: @kraskevich In point #1 you are trying to find the convex hull?

Comment: @YeshwanthVenkatesh Yes, `(A[i], i)` is a point for each i. In the point 3, there are 4 cases depending in the sign of the two differences. I showed one of them. In point 1, I just get 4 points that maximize four values (x[i] + y[i] etc.). It's not a convex hull. It's just four points with this property.

Answer (score 16):

We can surely use some math here. Try to Expand the Function you are trying to maximise.
**F(i,j) = |A[i] - A[j]| + |i - j|**
Expanding it will give us 4 values of F.

```
 1. A[i] - A[j] + i - j   equals to [A[i] + i] - [A[j]+j]
 2. -A[i] + A[j] + i - j  equals to [-A[i] + i] - [-A[j]+j]
 3. A[i] - A[j] + j - i   equals to [A[i] - i] - [A[j]-j]
 4. -A[i] + A[j] + j - i  equals to [-A[i] - i] - [-A[j]-j]
```

**Compute the Maximum and Minimum Value of [A[i] + i],[-A[i] + i],[A[i] - i],[-A[i] - i] for all elements in vector/array.** call it max1,max2,max3,max4 and min1,min2,min3,min4.

Your Answer is Max((max1-min1),(max2-min2),(max3-min3),(max4-min4)).

Here is the Problem Link if anyone is interested :- [Problem Link](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/maximum-absolute-difference/)

Below is my implementation in c++

```
int Solution::maxArr(vector<int> &A) {
int max1 = INT_MIN,max2 = INT_MIN,max3 = INT_MIN,max4 = INT_MIN,ans = INT_MIN;
int min1 = INT_MAX,min2 = INT_MAX,min3 = INT_MAX,min4 = INT_MAX;
for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
    max1 = max(max1,A[i] + i);
    max2 = max(max2,A[i] - i);
    max3 = max(max3,-A[i]+i);
    max4 = max(max4,-A[i]-i);

    min1 = min(min1,A[i] + i);
    min2 = min(min2,A[i] - i);
    min3 = min(min3,-A[i]+i);
    min4 = min(min4,-A[i]-i);

}


    ans = max(ans,max1 - min1);
    ans = max(ans,max2 - min2);
    ans = max(ans,max3 - min3);
    ans = max(ans,max4 - min4);

return ans;
```

}

Comment: Very well explained.

Comment: I have a question, suppose we attain the maximum among max1-min1, max2-min2, max3-min3, max4-min4 at indices i = i* and j = j*, how do we make sure A[i*] ,A[j*] & i*,j* indeed satisfy the comparison conditions which gave rise to that max b/c we generated all combinations w/o worrying about actual order b/w A[i*] ,A[j*] & i*,j*

Answer (score 6):

As described by **Kraskevich**, I applied the same algorithm. The complexity of the code is O(4*n)+O(4*n), thus making the overall complexity  **O(n)**.

Here is the code.

```
int Solution::maxArr(vector<int> &A) {
int n=A.size(),max1=INT_MIN,max2=INT_MIN,max3=INT_MIN,max4=INT_MIN,ans=INT_MIN;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    max1=max(max1,A[i]+i);
    max2=max(max2,-A[i]+i);
    max3=max(max3,A[i]-i);
    max4=max(max4,-A[i]-i);
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    ans=max(ans,max1-A[i]-i);
    ans=max(ans,max2+A[i]-i);
    ans=max(ans,max3-A[i]+i);
    ans=max(ans,max4+A[i]+i);
}
return ans;
}
```

Comment: You dont need two loops, It can be done in one loop only

Answer (score 4):

**O(N) Time Complexity and O(1) Space complexity solution**

This question can be solved in O(N) Time and O(1) space complexity by using simple mathematics concepts of absolute operator.

We can deduce this express into 4 different forms after removing the absolute operator and applying specific conditions.

Cases can be A[i]>A[j] or A[i]<=A[j] and simultaneously i>j and i<=j can be the cases so using these conditions we can formulate 4 different expressions which eliminate use of absolute operator.

After that we just need to find the maximum value possible through each expression by iterating on array of numbers only once.

If you still face any difficulties while solving this question then you can refer to the video solution

Video Link:- https://youtu.be/Ov4weYCIipg

Answer (score 2):

```
public int maxArr(ArrayList<Integer> A) 
{    
  int n=A.size(),max1=A.get(0),max2=A.get(0),int min1=A.get(0),min2=A.get(0),ans=0;

  for(int i=0;i<n; i++){
    max1=max(max1, A.get(i)+i);
    max2=max(max2, A.get(i)-i);
    min1=min(min1,  A.get(i)+i);
    min2=min(min2, A.get(i)-i);
  }

   ans = max(ans, (max2 - min2));
   ans = max(ans, (max1 - min1));

   return ans;
}
```

Here

```
int max1 = INT_MIN, max2 = INT_MIN;
int min1 = INT_MAX, min2 = INT_MAX;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the java solution to your problem.

```
public class Solution {
public int maxArr(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
    if(A.size() < 2) return 0;
    int res =Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max1=Integer.MIN_VALUE,max2=Integer.MIN_VALUE,min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE,min2=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i =0; i < A.size(); ++i){
        max1 = Math.max(A.get(i) + i, max1);
        min1 = Math.min(A.get(i) + i, min1);

        max2 = Math.max(A.get(i) - i, max2);
        min2 = Math.min(A.get(i) - i, min2);
    }

    res = Math.max(max1-min1, res);
    res = Math.max(max2-min2, res);
    return res;
  }                    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

conceptually speaking i can think of a very simple solution:

Here we are given that we need to maximize the |A[i] - A[j]| + |i - j|
What does this mean ? => if you think of the numbers on a number line along the x-axis it will help with visualization.

Lets think of the second part: |i-j| => if you think about this - it represent distance between any two points. the distance will always be fixed too.

Now if we can think of a way to add this distance to our array such that the it increases the distance A[i] - A[j] by a fixed amount - half of our problem is solved.

Here comes three things in consideration:

1. What if both are positive
2. What if both are negative
3. What if one is positive and one is negative

Remember you gotta increase the distance between A[i] and A[j] by fixed amount.
for 1 and 3 if you shift both the numbers in positive direction by the amount of their indices i.e. i and j. your problem is solved.

for 2 you gotta shift the number towards more negative.

now all we need is find difference of min and max separately for both the arrays,
one with larger absolute value will be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`f(i, j) = |A[i] - A[j]| + |i - j|` can be simplified in the following ways (based on definition of `abs()` ):

```
a) (A[j]-j)-(A[i]-i)
b) (A[j]+j)-(A[i]+i)
c) (A[i]+i)-(A[j]+j)
d) (A[i]-i)-(A[j]-j)
```

`for 0< i,j < N` - `a` & `d` are similar, as well as `b` & `c`. So if we can calculate an array of `A[i]-i` and `A[i]+i` and find max difference within it, we will have the answer.

```
  public class Solution {
        public int maxArr(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
            int n = A.size();
            int max = 0;
            int []a = new int [n];
            int []b = new int [n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                a[i]=A.get(i)-i;
                b[i]=A.get(i)+i;
            }
            Arrays.sort(a);
            Arrays.sort(b);
            max = Math.max(a[n-1]-a[0], b[n-1]-b[0]);
            return max;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation reference

```
int Solution::maxArr(vector<int> &A) {
    int max1 , max2 , min1 , min2;
    max1 = max2 = INT_MIN;
    min1 = min2 = INT_MAX;
    int N = A.size();
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        max1 = max(max1,A[i]+i);
        max2 = max(max2,A[i]-i);
        min1 = min(min1,A[i]+i);
        min2 = min(min2,A[i]-i);
    }
    int ans = 0;
    ans = max(ans,max1-min1);
    ans = max(ans,max2-min2);
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we require 4 cases. If we open the mod, there are 4 cases:

```
 a) (A[j]-j)-(A[i]-i)
 b) (A[j]+j)-(A[i]+i)
 c) (A[i]+i)-(A[j]+j)
 d) (A[i]-i)-(A[j]-j)
```

But (a) and (d) are same. So are (b) and (c). Hence the problem melts to 2 cases.

```java
int max1 = INT_MIN , max2 = INT_MIN , min1 = INT_MAX , min2 = INT_MAX;

for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
{
    max1 = max(max1 , A[i] + i);
    min1 = min(min1 , A[i] + i);
    max2 = max(max2 , A[i] - i);
    min2 = min(min2 , A[i] - i);
}

return max(max1 - min1 , max2 - min2);
```

Comment: Can you please explain why A,D/B,C are the same?

Answer (score 0):

This's also fine, to reduce extra lines of last step:

```
      int n=A.size(),max1=INT_MIN,max2=INT_MIN,min1=INT_MAX,min2=INT_MAX,ans=INT_MIN;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        max1=max(max1, A[i]+i);
        min1=min(min1, A[i]+i);
        max2=max(max2, -A[i]+i);
        min2=min(min2, -A[i]+i);
  }
  ans = max((max1-min1), (max2 - min2));
return ans;
```