# Maximum sum of pairwise absolute difference of values in multiple arrays and index

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have 5 arrays A, B, C, D, E each of size N. Now we need to find the

```
max(|A[i] - A[j]| + |B[i] - B[j]| + |C[i] - C[j]| + |D[i] - D[j]| + |E[i] - E[j]| + |i - j|)       where 1<=i<j<=N.
```

I'm well aware of the problem to find `max(|A[i] - A[j]| + |i - j|)` for a single array in `O(n)`. But its solution method doesn't seem to be applicable in this case.

So my question is how to solve this problem in `O(nlogn)` runtime or if possible `O(n)` runtime.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you can solve this in linear time, as you would have to calculate the value for each `i-j-pair`. Maybe I am just missing something tough. Is there any more information about the arrays?

Comment: Can it be done in ```O(nlogn)``` time, can u suggest me something . @CodingTil

Comment: Do you have a link or name for the single array algorithm?

Comment: Please have a look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40273280/11506111) @RBarryYoung

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[kraskevich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40273280/11506111) for the 2D case generalizes to d dimensions, with running time O(2<sup>d</sup> d n). With d = 6, this is O(n). For each of the 2<sup>d</sup> d-dimensional vectors c with ±1 coordinates, we find the input vector v that maximizes the dot product c⋅v. For each of these vectors v, we evaluate the objective when they are paired with each vector w.